# When a thread is reading a json file, how to make sure all other threads are in wait in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I'm creating dynamic threads as shown below

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(brnchCount);
Semaphore smp = new Semaphore(1);
for (Object o : list) {
service.submit(new MyTask(o, projectId, serverConfigFilePath, path, packName, executeParam, smp));
}
service.shutdown();
```

Each call has to access a json file and update data to the same. As all threads are accessing the same file, its throwing exception and corrupting the file.

I tried using the 'Semaphore' to acquire the method which manipulates the file. Still m getting the same error.
How can all the threads read and write the json without any exception ?

Comment: Inter- or intra-process? Doesn't a `synchronized` block work already? How are you using the semaphore inside `MyTask`?

Comment: If the method that opens and closes the file is synchronized, you shouldn't have this issue

Comment: Show us the code that manipulates the data and where you acquire the semaphore. It's very easy to write threaded code wrong. For example if you protect individual steps in your process by semaphore but not the relevant sequences *together*, then it's easy to get the problems you describe.

Comment: needs more code.. what is `MyTask`?